# How do you vertically align layers in Photoshop so that they are one below another touching their borders?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a bunch of layers in Photoshop CC 2017.

I want to make them be aligned in a way that layer 2's top border touches layer 1's bottom border and layer 3's top border touches layer 2's bottom border, etc. I.e. be in a column one below the other, possibly horizontally centered.

Is there a way to make not *not* by hand? I'm not talking about **Edit -> Auto-Align Layers...** because I didn't see such an option on it.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. There's nothing automated that will do that (unless you can find a script perhaps). The way I usually do this is to enable snapping.

Comment: @BillyKerr, thank you! It just seems like something so obvious to add as automated I expected it.